# Firebase cloud function concurrent promises for https.onRequest

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Inside a Firebase cloud function, there is one `set` call on a database reference, and a concurrent `once("value")` call on another reference, both of which return promises. There is also an `update` inside the `once`'s `then` handler, and the handler does strictly more than the `update`.

Now, this is an https.onRequest so we can't return the promises, e.g. can't do `Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(blah blah blah)`. So how should we return the `response.status(200).send(dictionary)` while ensuring the asynchronous calls complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically stated the solution already:

```
Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(blah blah blah)
```

The list of promises passed to `Promise.all()` should contain all the promises you need to wait for.  Where it says "blah blah blah", put a function that sends your result:

```
results => {
    response.status(200).send(dictionary)
}
```

Might want to also use a `catch` to send an error response in case something goes wrong.

If this isn't what you're looking for, please show some code that you've actually tried.

Comment: I see. Will calling `response.status(200).send(dictionary)` terminate the function execution? If not then it's also possible to set the response status in one of the promises instead of in the handler for Promise.all? Btw, how does response.status() work under the hood?

Comment: With Cloud Functions, HTTP functions are terminated when a response is sent.  For all other types of function, it should return a promise to indicate completion.

Comment: so if I do `return Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(response.status(200))` wouldn't the function already be terminated by the `response.status` statement before the Promise.all ever gets the chance to return? or does `response.status` send a return value to the Promise.all?

Comment: Don't bother returning the promise.  Just sent the result when all the work is done.  Cloud Functions will wait for that response to be sent, or time out.  Perhaps you are misunderstanding what `then` does.  The function passed there gets executed only after its promise is resolved.

Comment: I see. Thank you